# Creating components from events of other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm fairly new to React and I am having some trouble understanding the lifecycle of components.

I've currently got a navbar and navbutton components, I want each navbutton to trigger something different. I don't want to change page, I want to display more components within the same page.

I've got my button setup so I can do the below.

```
<NavButton text="Searches" onClick={
    function () {
        console.log('test');
    }
} />
</div>
```

Is there anyway in that event I can say, create / display a different component elsewhere in my DOM?

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- give your component state, and add a showdetail flag (set to false in `getInitialState()`)
- clicking updates state (`setState({showDetail: true})`)
- rendering made dependent on state

Render could then look like this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <NavItem props={foo}>
      {this.state.showDetail? <NavSubItem props={bar}/> : null }
    </NavItem>
  )
}
```

In that way, the `<NavSubItem>` is only rendered if showDetail == true.